Decorating python properties with an observable pattern
I'm trying to create an observable decorator that adds the method "add_observer" to a property.
The main issue I'm having is that I do not know how to treat the getter. It would be amazing if I could extend the underlying property with the method somehow.
class observable:
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.observers = []
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = None
        self.name = fget.__name__

    def add_observer(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)

    def setter(self, fset):
        self.fset = fset
        return self

    def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:

        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"Setter not defined for property {self.name}")
        self.fset(obj, value)

        for observer in self.observers:
            observer(value)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self


class Options:

    def __init__(self):
        self._debug: bool = False

    @observable
    def debug(self) -> bool:
        return self._debug

    @debug.setter
    def debug(self, debug: bool):
        self._debug = debug


opt = Options()
print(opt.debug)
opt.debug.add_observer(lambda value: print(f"Debug is {value}"))
opt.debug = True
opt.debug = False

<__main__.observable object at 0x7f446f854500>
Debug is True
Debug is False

I cannot use opt.debug as a boolean value.
I tried alternatives such as modifying the owner with owner.add_observable(owner.debug, lambda x: 'hello!') which is pretty close to what I want but not close enough. Mostly because I wanted autocomplete to work.
Also, I'm getting a shadowing error on the IDE that @property does not trigger, how come?:


It would probably be simpler to subclass property rather than to try to reimplement most of it in a custom descriptor. Keep in mind that the problem is that opt.debug really does evaluate to a bool, not the descriptor bound to Options.debug.

Do you want observers to be associated with the descriptor, or the pair consisting of an instance and the descriptor. That is, if you have two instances of Options named opt1 and opt2, do you want opt1.debug and opt2.debug to have separate sets of observers, or share the same set?

@chepner I just realized that there's only one observable instance per class. I'd like them to have separate set of observers. Or at least separatable by using a data structure if necessary.

OK, then observers must either be a mapping of a (hashable) owner to a list of functions, or each owner has to store its own list of functions directly. I can post answer if you can clarify whether we can assume owners (like Options) will be hashable.

It's not completely clear how you are expecting this to work, but there are several issues with this approach.

Your __get__ method never returns the value of the property because it never calls self.fget. A descriptor's __get__ method takes a reference to an instance and a reference to the class, and if the instance is not None is supposed to return the property value for the instance, and if the class is not None, is supposed to return a reference to the property object.
By way of example, the python equivalent of the native property class is something like:


def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
    if obj is None:
        return self
    if self.fget is None:
        raise AttributeError("Attribute has no getter")
    return self.fget(obj)


I'm not sure if it is your intention or not, but the way you have implemented this, when an observer is added, it is added for the class, not for the instance.
That is, in your implementation, when you call opt.debug.set_observer, that observer will be called when the debug property is set on any instance of the Options class, not just the instance referenced by the variable opt, because properties exist at the class level. That is, there is only one instance of observable for the Options class's debug property.
If that is indeed the desired behavior for your use case, and you implment __get__ as described above, then the way you would access your observable instance instead of the value of the debug property is to call type(opt).debug.add_observer instead of opt.debug.add_observer (or alternatively Options.debug.add_observer).
If you want to be able to add per instance observers, then you need to come up with another implementation.

Just as an extra tip, there is a better way to set the name of the property than reading it from the getter method. When you define a descriptor, if your descriptor class has a method called __set_name__, that will be called with a reference to the class the name of the property as part of class construction.


Putting it all together, your example could be rewritten as follows.
class observable:
    def __init__(self, fget, fset = None):
        self.observers = []
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_observer(self, observer):
        self.observers.append(observer)

    def setter(self, fset):
        self.fset = fset
        return self

    def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"Setter not defined for property {self.name}")
        self.fset(obj, value)

        for observer in self.observers:
            observer(value)
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError(f"Attribute {name} has no getter")
        return self.fget(obj)


class Options:
    def __init__(self):
        self._debug: bool = False

    @observable
    def debug(self) -> bool:
        return self._debug

    @debug.setter
    def debug(self, debug: bool):
        self._debug = debug


opt = Options()
print(opt.debug)
type(opt).debug.add_observer(lambda value: print(f"Debug is {value}"))
opt.debug = True
opt.debug = False

opt2 = Options()
opt2.debug = True # the observer will be called here, too, even though no observer was set on opt2


Note that every instance of observable shares the same set of observers. You probably want something like type(opt).debug.add_observer(opt, lambda  value: ...), with the corresponding changs to add_observer to allow the given observer to be associated with opt specifically.

I explain that the observers are shared in my answer. Yes, if per instance observers are part of the OP's requirements, it would be possible to pass the instance as an argument to add_observer, but then you would also need a different data structure to hold the observers -- a simple list of observer functions wouldn't work -- which would also require a modification of the __set__ method to call only the observers set on the particular instance. Without knowing more about the OP's requirements, I did not suggest those changes.

@couteau Thanks for the insight. I didn't know about the instance lifecycle of decorators. So, as I understand now, an instance of observable will be created per class that is decorated. I'd like to do it per property, if not possible I'd use some data structure to match the list of observers. Do you have any suggestion?

It’s per property, but it’s per property for the entire class. So if you have a class with two decorated properties, each property will have its own list of observers, but those lists of observers will be shared by every instance of the class. If it’s a singleton class, as an options class often is, that may not matter.
